# Use HM-10 to detect Estimot beacon distance

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, hm-10

I would like to make my Arduino+HM-10 detect Estimote beacon distance without using phone connection but I’m not sure it’s even possible.

Can I detect the beacon only with HM-10?
Can I estimate the distance between my Arduino+HM-10 and the beacon? I know Apple didn’t publish the algorithm but I have already estimated distance to a beacon with a Cordova app on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to use RSSI and algorithm that you have to choose depending of what you want to achieve.

Please, find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937888/calculate-distance-between-arduino-ble-shield-and-phone/38953649#38953649), in order to get more details, especially on BLE technology limitations for distance measurement.

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! Is it possible without phone and without wifi ?

Comment: Of course, it is possible. You have to read BLE RSSI value on your Arduino (ask it from HM-10), and then you have to use this RSSI value to estimate the distance (either by simple or more advanced algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and with using a Firmware newer than v538 (you can check your version via the command "AT-VERS?") it is quite easy as well.

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

//     Connect HM10      Arduino Uno
//     Pin 1/TXD          Pin 7
//     Pin 2/RXD          Pin 8

void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     mySerial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
     String message;
     if (Serial.available()) {
          c = Serial.read();
          mySerial.print(c);
     }
     if (mySerial.available()) {
          message = "";
          delay(10);
          while (mySerial.available()) {
          c = mySerial.read();
          message = message + c;
     }
          Serial.println(message);
}
```

This is the basic code to get a connection with your HM10 [the rx/tx pins might vary]. If you send a "AT" through your serial monitor, the HM10 should give back an "OK" now.

You might need to setup your HM10 as a BLE central device before you can start scanning for Beacons. This is done by sending:

AT-ROLE1 //sets central role

AT-IMME1 //should work without prior activation

AT-RESET //restarts the HM10

After that, if you send "AT-DISI?" through the serial monitor, the HM10 should start looking for iBeacons and (case it finds one) give back the following [the P´s are placeholders]:

OK+DISC[P0:P1:P2:P3:P4]

This message contains the POWER (sending signal power) and RSSI (recieved signal strength) of the iBeacon, from which the distance to the beacon can be deducted.

The last 2 digits of P3 contain the POWER of the iBeacon, P4 is the RSSI value.
[note: the 2 Power digits are hex values, you need to convert them into decimal values first --- the number should be somewhere around 190]

The most common way to measure distance between the Beacon (as far as I know) is:

**distance = 10 ^ ((POWER-RSSI) / 10n) [n is between 2 and 4, I use 2]**

:) I hope that helps and good luck on your project.

Comment: It should be noted though, that range calculation is a rather unprecise thing with iBeacons. Thus, don´t expect too much of it